# Other than lots of connections, what might cause nginx to return a "worker_connections are not enough" error?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My website recently started erroring, with the client showing a 500 error or not able to connect at all. Checking the nginx error log shows a bunch of "768 worker_connections are not enough" errors. I find this odd because my website is not very popular; I'd be surprised if I were even getting 768 connections per *day*, let alone concurrently.

The error seems to have only started occurring a few days ago, and I haven't touched any of the nginx config files in months, so I don't think it's a directly-me-caused issue like [this one](https://serverfault.com/a/830956). I'm not really sure how to go about debugging this; any suggestions?